# "Input file specified two times." error when using Cygwin sort on Windows

Tags: java, windows, shell, cygwin

I'm building a desktop app that uses Cygwin to execute shell scripts on Windows 10. Ideally, users wouldn't have to install Cygwin because I'm putting the relevant exe files in my project. I have Cygwin's "sh.exe" in my project which I can call without an absolute path and it seems to be running grep, zcat, awk, etc with no issues.

It looks like I'm running into the issue explained in https://www.question-defense.com/2010/08/25/windows-7-cygwin-sort-input-file-specified-two-times where Window's cmd is using it's own sort rather than Cygwin's sort.exe and you have to put the path of the sort.exe in the script. So it looks like the user would have to download Cygwin which would somewhat defeats the purpose of my project because I want a hassle-free experience for users. I don't want them to have to download dependencies.

The only resolution I've thought of is to include the sort.exe in the project and replace the "sort" string in the script with the Windows path of the sort.exe, which I think would be in the directory where the user launched the app; maybe System.getProperty("user.dir").

Is there a better solution?

MobaXTerm seems to have got it down. They have a CygUtils plugin, which you have to download and put in the right place, but I imagine it wouldn't be hard for them to have their application come with CygUtils. I'm trying to do something like that.

Comment: You could place a shellscript `cygsort.sh` into your PATH, which just invokes the cygwin sort tool via an absolute path. BTW, you will run into the same problem with the commands `find``, `more` or `type`.

Comment: That would require the user to update their PATH, right?

Comment: This would be the cleanest solution, but if you really, really want to avoid it, you could put the script into a directory where you already know that it must be in the user's path, for example into the same directory where i.e. _zcat_ lives right now.

Comment: Another possibility would be to define the PATH in the global initialization files of the respective shell (/etc/profile and so on). This would allow you to keep your own scripts in a separate directory.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue while using Cygwin. 
I renamed [cygwin64_folder]\bin\**sort** file to **csort** (or any other convenient name if you wish) and used **csort** command for my usage.